# Looping through array and pushing values to a MAP with a JSON object - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a JSON data structure with the following output

```
{
  { key: {"value" : valueData} },
  { key: {"value" : valueData} },
}
```

I am looping through an array, that has the key and valueData.

And I'm trying to build the loop in such a way that I assume would push to a map and then output it in that format when I log it

Comment: What is your input and what exactly do you expect as output? it's not very clear.

Comment: That output is not a valid format: your top-level object has no keys. Did you mean to use an array instead?